# Find the matrix of linear form $f \to \int_0^1 f(x)dx$

Tags: linear-algebra

On $P_{3}(t)$ = {$x(t)$ = $a_{0}$ + $a_{1}t$ + $a_{2}$$t^{2}$ +$a_{3}$$t^{3}$}. Find the matrix of linear mapping $f(x)$ = $\int_{0}^{1}f(t)dt$ on basis $I$={$1$, $t$, $t^2$, $t^3$}.

Comment: Does question b) means find the matrix of linear function $f$ ? Hint: as $f$ is a linear form, it is a $1 \times 4$ matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your linear form is from a $4$-dimensional space with base $(1,t,t^2,t^3)$ into $\mathbb R$. So your matrix is in fact $1\times 4$. The entries of the matrix are the evaluation of the base vectors in coordinates of the base in the image space, which is in this case simply (1), so the coordinates are simply the evaluations at the base.

So for each of these base vectors determine $\int_0^1 b_i(t)\,dt$.

Comment: you mean is $f(1)$=$1$, $f(t)$=$\frac{1}{2}$,... right?

Comment: @NguyễnĐứcBá Exactly, yes. So your linear form in coordinates $(1,t,t^2,t^3)$ is given by the $1\times 4$ matrix of these values.